# Image for yearbook cover too big to upload

Tags: images, resize, file-size, file-format, file-conversion

I'm using a new yearbook design software this year which is all web-based.

I'm trying to upload a vector image for the cover but it's too big. I saved it as a jpg and tif with a transparent background and it's still too big (still over a gig).

Any tips on how to make it smaller?

I used CS back in college, but since I graduated almost 10 years ago, I'm having to reteach myself everything as I go.

Comment: Hi ALE3125, Welcome to GD.SE! Your image for the yearbook is over 1 Gb? You will need to provide us with more information for us to give you any sort of answer. You would need quite a big graphic (say ~90+ inch, 300 PPI) for a jpg image to be over a Gb.

Comment: Hi! Any reason why you need a transparent background for a cover? What is the dimension of the cover? What was the resolution you used for your JPG and TIFF? Was your TIFF flattened? As AndrewH mentioned, to get a 1gb JPG, that needs to be quite a huge file! There's certainly a conversion mistake you're doing but we can't really help you without knowing at least the dimension and resolution!